# const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud initialize

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a function which takes a

```
const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input
```

as input. I currently have a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 but i cant turn it into a pointer for some reason.

Is the sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr are boost shared_ptr?
If so how do you initialize the pointer to an object that already exists?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64450/const-sensor_msgs::pointcloud2constptr&-cloud-initialize/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use the Boost `make_shared` function to create a pointer to the existing cloud.

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 p;

const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input = boost::make_shared<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(p);
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3